# Setting log level for plugin project in Grails

Tags: java, grails, logging, plugins, log4j

I have a grails project with a plugin project whose codes i use in main codes. I have set the logger in main project to info level using "info 'grails.app'". It works for all the classes in the main project but not for those in plugin project. Does the scope of grails.app wont cover plugin classes? If that is so then what is the solution. If not what can be possible issue over here. I am debugging my system and want to see the issue by getting into debug level (ofcourse replacing info by debug) but the logging statements from the plugin classes are not printed.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific logger for plugins `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins`. Read more at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is overriding the log level (though I have no idea why).

You can try to explicitly set the log level for your plugin using the log4j closure in Config.groovy, as shown in the Grails docs:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging